# Unable to find the .lit file reader app clit

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have some lit files I want to convert from Microsoft reader files to something my other devices can read. My friend says I should have clit, in

```
$ which clit
/usr/bin/clit
```

but I cannot find it. I tried `locate clit` but the results are unrelated. So then I tried `sudo apt-get install clit` but it says package not found.
Is clit a standard package? where can I find it?

Comment: Hiya folks! I'd just like to remind everyone that when we use the site, we have to follow the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct), and that we need to be respectful and considerate with what we do and say.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Download [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) - this will read your *LIT* format files, and also be able to convert them to other formats.

**OR**

you can install the *clit* program by `sudo apt-get install convlit`

Answer (score 39):

The general solution to the question “Which package provides file *X*?” is to use the in-packages search feature of the official site's [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com) page.

Scroll down to **Search the contents of packages** (the *second* search form on the page — using the first is an easy mistake and will give frustrating results).

Enter your desired filename in the search field and hit <kbd>Search</kbd>, and there it is:

[image: Screenshot of the Ubuntu Package Search page results, for a search of package contents containing "clit", showing the convlit package]

Comment: `apt-file` sometimes can be even better: it has more features and searches *all* the sources you have enabled in `/etc/sources.list`, i.e. also third-party sources, which package.ubuntu.com wouldn't search (which is a downside if you don't have all the standard sources enabled, but you can still set `apt-file` to sync with another custom `sources.list` which has all of them enabled).

Comment: Even more easy way to find out which package in repositories contains your non-existing command is to run it. I entered `clit` in the terminal and got an answer that it is not installed and I should run `sudo apt-get install convlit`. Easy, right? This feature is provided by the package `command-not-found` which exists in Ubuntu right out of the box.